# Ajax long polling after page refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have an AJAX long polling request below:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "events_controller.php",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {          
            eventsTimer = setTimeout(function(){eventsTimerHandler()}, 1000);
        }
});
```

On the server, if some event happens then it will return what has happened and the request above will display a notification.

A problem I am having is if I do something on the browser to trigger an event that will happen in say 10 seconds in the future and then immediately go to a different page, it will create a new long polling request but the previous one is still active and no notification will be sent to the user.

I hope I'm making sense.